# mysql search query in text with and without word boundaries

Tags: mysql

I have a product table which I am searching with simple like clause, I want to search with boundary and without boundary results.

```
SELECT *
FROM products 
WHERE title LIKE '%cold%'
```

for example if this query return following rows,

```
coldrum
rum cold
coldwine
cold wind
```

I want the result like this (first with boundaries and rest without boundaries)

```
cold wind
rum cold
coldrum
coldwine
```

Well, Actual SQL is like this,

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS distinct p.*, pd.*, m.*, i.image, if(s.status,
s.specials_new_products_price, null) as specials_new_products_price, if(s.status,
s.specials_new_products_price, if (pv.products_price, pv.products_price,
p.products_price)) as final_price from products p left join products_variants pv on
(p.products_id = pv.products_id and pv.is_default = 1) left join manufacturers m 
using(manufacturers_id) left join specials s on (p.products_id = s.products_id) left
join products_images i on (p.products_id = i.products_id and i.default_flag = 1),
products_description pd, categories c, products_to_categories p2c where 
p.products_status = 1 and p.products_id = pd.products_id and pd.language_id = 1 and
p.products_id = p2c.products_id and p2c.categories_id = c.categories_id and
(pd.products_tags like '%gold%' or pd.products_name like '%gold%') order by
p.products_date_added desc limit 0, 20
```

Comment: What's the difference in your existing output and desired output other than sorting order? both are same

Comment: i want with boundaries word first and searched text within a word later.

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
SELECT *
FROM products  
WHERE title LIKE '%cold%'order by 
case when title like 'cold %' then 0 
when title like '% cold' then 1 else title end
```

Comment: That sort should be inverse of that. Currently it does in reverse order. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/869b98/11

Comment: `I want the result like this (first with boundaries and rest without boundaries)`

Comment: I have posted the actual long SQL for reference. Thanks.

Comment: create sql fiddle for your query @JigneshVyas

Comment: @sathish Thanks. I tried this with my actual sql but it doesn't seems to work. ".....and (pd.products_tags like '%gold%' or pd.products_name like '%gold%') order by (LENGTH(pd.products_name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(pd.products_name, ' ', ''))+1) asc limit 0, 20", in addition it has like clause in two fields (products_tags and products_name) as well.

Comment: @JigneshVyas your real query its big i can not understand easily so if your create all tables and query in sql fiddle.com then i will try to help you

Comment: @Sathish  That's great, Let me try to create some simulation in fiddle and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @Sathish created the structure at fiddle. Pl have a look.

Comment: @JigneshVyas PI means where is fiddle url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE title LIKE '%cold%' ORDER BY 
(LENGTH(title) - LENGTH(REPLACE(title, ' ', ''))+1) DESC;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8eb76/1)